# RedirectToAction after Owin ExternalLogin adds # hash to the url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, owin

After logging in using google auth and redirecting to home/index I get a hash # added to the url.

Now I noticed that `StackOverflow.com` has a similar thing, after I logged in using facebook I got redirected to:

`http://stackoverflow.com/#_=_`

My controller code is quite standard:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    var loginInfo = await HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (loginInfo == null)
    {
        return Content("failed");
    }
    // removed rest of the code to identify problem  
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Does anybody know why this hash # appears in the Url, and can I get rid of it?

Comment: The fragment is added for security purposes when no redirect_uri was set during the OAuth process. See: http://homakov.blogspot.com/2013/03/redirecturi-is-achilles-heel-of-oauth.html

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thank You, you should add this as an answer